# Django Python: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'arcetina'

Tags: python, django

I get the following error when trying to filter on a `QuerySet` of user posts, with a `ForeignKey` author. Django has problem with the following line:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(author=components[0])
```

And spews out this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'arcetina'
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
def post_list(request):
    global posts

    context = {'posts' : posts}

    for post in posts:
        if not post.field:
            post.field = 'Unspecified'

    if request.method == "POST":
        searchRegex = request.POST.get("searchregex")
        components = searchRegex.split()

        if searchRegex == "-reversedate":
            posts = posts.reverse()
            context = {'posts' : posts}

        if "-user" in searchRegex:
            posts = Post.objects.filter(author=components[0])

    return render(request, 'webapp/threadfeed.html', context)
```

And here is my `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    up_vote = 0 # num of up votes
    down_vote = 0 #num of down votes
    vote_total = up_vote - down_vote
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, blank=True)

    CHOICES = [
        ('Hardware and OS', 'Hardware and OS'),
        ('Desktops', 'Desktops'),
        ('Tablets', 'Tablets'),
        ('Phones', 'Phones'),
        ('Wearables', 'Wearables'),
        ('Windows', 'Windows'),
        ('Mac OS X', 'Mac OS X'),
        ('Linux and Unix', 'Linux and Unix'),
        ('Programming and Computer Science', 'Programming and Computer Science'),
        ('Software Development', 'Software Development'),
        ('Web Development (Front)', 'Web Development (Front)'),
        ('Web Development (Back)', 'Web Development (Back)'),
        ('Mobile Development', 'Mobile Development'),
        ('Game Development', 'Game Development'),
        ('Algorithms and Data Structures', 'Algorithms and Data Structures'),
        ('Databases', 'Databases'),
        ('IDE / Text Editors', 'IDE / Text Editors'),
        ('Tutorial', 'Tutorial'),
        ('Opinion', 'Opinion'),
        ('Miscellaneous', 'Miscellaneous')
    ]
    field = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=200, default='Unspecified')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title.encode('utf-8')

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('blog_post_detail', (), 
                {
                    'slug' :self.slug,
                })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're passing a string to filter a field that is an integer. (Actually it's a foreign key, but that is stored as an integer ID.)

If you want to filter on a field in the related model, you need to use the double-underscore syntax:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__username=components[0])
```

Note also that it's an extremely bad idea to have a global `posts` queryset, especially as you're mutating it in your view. All requests will see the same list; once you've filtered it by user, or reversed it, the next request will see the already-modified queryset. You should remove the global variable and query the Posts model from scratch each time.